# I can't block all except me in htaccess

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

I have this code in my htaccess (wordpress):

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
# BEGIN WordPress
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

I have added all type of codes to block everyone except me, i try with:

```
order deny,allow
deny from all
allow from 'myIp'
```

but not works, maybe because I put this code in wrong place.

I try with this, too, and nothing:

```
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^123\.456\.789\.123$
```

Can you help me, please? I want to access with my ip to index and the rest to google.com, for example.

Comment: Remove quotes in `allow from 'myIp'`. Is it allowing everyone or is it blocking everyone?

Answer (score 0):

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^12345$
RewriteRule ^ http://google.com/ [L,R]
# BEGIN WordPress
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Comment: Thanks, but if I put my public Ip in RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} the code send me to google.

Comment: Ok, i needed 2 conditions:

RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} ^xx\.xx\.xx\.xx$
# BEGIN WordPress
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]

RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^xx\.xx\.xx\.xx$
RewriteRule ^ http://google.com/ [L,R]

Thank you very much!